# Odds of run of successes in Bernoulli trial

Tags: probability

What is the formula that gives the odds I will have a run of *k* successes in a row, where each trial has a *p* chance of success, if I ran the trial *n* times?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to compute the answer yourself?

Comment: I suggest you try working it out by hand for a simple case, such as $k=2$, $p=0.4$, and $n=5$. There are only $32$ possible outcomes of running the trial $5$ times. You can list each outcome with its probability of occurring, and then add up the probabilities for the outcomes that contain two consecutive successes. If you do this for a few simple cases, you might get some ideas for how to answer the general question.

Comment: This is a fairly difficult problem to solve in general - see here for solutions for given $k$ and $n$: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21825/probability-of-a-run-of-k-successes-in-a-sequence-of-n-bernoulli-trials